# Validation not working in Rest API

Tags: rest, spring-data

I am not able to work with the validation annotations. I am not getting the messages configured for them when passing values that should be caught in validation by the annotations.

Controller:

```java
@RestController
public class AccountConfigController {

    @Autowired
    AccountConfigService accountConfigService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/${project.version}/acctconfigs", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public List<AccountConfigViewDTO> viewAccountConfig() throws BankServiceException {
        List<AccountConfigViewDTO> accountConfigDTOList= accountConfigService.viewAccountConfig();
        return accountConfigDTOList;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/${project.version}/acctconfigs", method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public boolean editAccountConfig(@RequestBody @Valid AccountConfigEditDTO accountConfigEditDTO) throws BankServiceException {
        return accountConfigService.editAccountConfig(accountConfigEditDTO);
    }
}
```

There are two DTO's used as I was not getting way of doing the needed using one.

AccountConfigEditDTO:

```java
public class AccountConfigEditDTO implements java.io.Serializable {

    @JsonProperty("accountconfig")
    @Valid
    private List<AccountConfigViewDTO> accountConfigViewDTOList;

    @NotBlank(message="accountconfig.lastUpdatedId.mandatory")
    @Size(max=10,message="accountconfig.lastUpdatedId.size")
    @JsonProperty("userId")
    private String lstUpdtId;

    //Getter and Setters and Constructors
}
```

AccountConfigViewDTO:

```java
public class AccountConfigViewDTO implements Serializable {

    @NotNull(message="newcustomer.accttype.mandatory")
    private char acctType;

    @NotEmpty(message="accountconfig.interest.mandatory")
    @Digits(integer=8 , fraction=4 , message="accountconfig.interest.size")
    private BigDecimal interestRate;

    @NotEmpty(message="accountconfig.interest.mandatory")
    @Digits(integer=8 , fraction=4 , message="accountconfig.minimumBalance.size")
    private BigDecimal minBalance;

    //Getters and Setters and constructors
 }
```

When I pass data like for example:

```
{
    "accountconfig" : [
        {
            "acctType": "C",
            "interestRate": "",
            "minBalance": 500
        },
        {
            "acctType":"S",
            "interestRate": 4.00,
            "minBalance": 5000.0
        }
    ],
    "userId": "admin"
}
```

I get

> {"errorCode":500,"errorMsg":"An unknown error occured."}

but not my custom message "Interest Rate is mandatory". I have given this error message mapping in the application.properties file.

Do let me know if there is any problem in the code?

Comment: Do you see any exceptions / stack traces on standard out?

Comment: And what is the value of your first `acctType` in your example data? Typo or invalid JSON?

Comment: No it should produce the not null validation message. As the value is not present. Also no error or exception in console too

Comment: Your data is no valid JSON. Is `"acctType": null` what you mean?

Comment: Yeah, that meant accType is NULL, but since character validation is having loads of problems please see the updated test now. The BigDecimal field should give the error message but it is not giving

Comment: You should update your question with which validation message you expect to occur instead of giving that additional explanation in a comment.

Comment: Also, reduce your example. Do not use `${project.version}` in your endpoints (for your example). Reduce your classes until only the BigDecimal is contained. This makes it easier for you and for us to trace down the problem.

Comment: I have reduced much but kept some parts so that other folks viewing do not come up with suggestion like that part is missing etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148866/discussion-between-florian-albrecht-and-mohit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually trying out various options I got a solution to my problem. So thought of posting it just in case some one else encounters this problem.

The solution was to add @Valid in the AccountConfigEditDTO in the List field:

```
public class AccountConfigEditDTO implements java.io.Serializable{


    @JsonProperty("accountconfig")
    private @Valid List<AccountConfigViewDTO> accountConfigViewDTOList;

    @NotBlank(message="accountconfig.lastUpdatedId.mandatory")
    @Size(max=10,message="accountconfig.lastUpdatedId.size")
    @JsonProperty("userId")
    private String lstUpdtId;
}
```

This did the trick. But still no luck with validating the char field, I think the only way for it is to make custom validator annotation.

One more thing what I understood for the above problem is validation was not going to the DTO in the List so adding @Valid did that trick. Do comment if someone has better explanation for it.

Comment: See my [example](https://github.com/Cepr0/restdemo/tree/master/src/main/java/restsdemo/example13), maybe it can help. Pay attention on [ErrorAttributes](https://github.com/Cepr0/restdemo/blob/master/src/main/java/restsdemo/RestDemo.java) Bean.